# Javascript external file causing Object Expected error in IE8 (Marketo)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, external

I've been pulling my hair out trying to solve this problem. We support IE8 and use a company called "Marketo" for some analytics. When I load their Javascript file as an external, then try to instantiate the class within the file, it throws a Javascript "Object expected" error in IE8. It does not cause this in Firefox or Safari.

However, when I manually paste the contents of the external inside a `<script>` tag, the class instantiates fine! It's only when the Javascript file is external that the problem is caused. I must use an external because Marketo updates their code regularly and I can't keep on top of the copying/pasting.

Here is the external: http://munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js

Here is how I load the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js"></script>
```

Here is how I instantiate the class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
mktoMunchkin("300-EOJ-215");
</script>
```

Using `setTimeout()` doesn't help anything (I thought maybe it was a slow server causing a timing issue):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    mktoMunchkin("300-EOJ-215");
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: Figured out what the problem was. We were delivering our webpage over HTTPS and pulling the Marketo munchkin.js file over HTTP, which for whatever reason IE8 (and not Firefox, Safari, etc.) had a problem with. Switched the URL to `https://munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js` and it was fine.

Comment: I was able to run this script with no errors in IE 8.  Not sure what exactly it's doing (and it takes a REALLY long time to run), but not errors are popping up in my IE 8 browser.

Comment: This worked for you in IE8 without error?

Comment: Here's the code I ran with no issues...`<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>testing...</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   mktoMunchkin("300-EOJ-215");
  </script>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: So weird, that works fine for me too, but in the context of our much longer and more complicated file it fails. *sigh* thanks IE8 for wasting my day! I'll keep investigating...

Comment: you should post your update as the answer and then others may be helped in the future if they stumble across a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was. We were delivering our webpage over HTTPS and pulling the Marketo munchkin.js file over HTTP, which for whatever reason IE8 (and not Firefox, Safari, etc.) had a problem with. Switched the URL to https://munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced very similar problem this morning for IE7 and IE8 on Windows.  Links on web pages built with aspx that have Marketo's munchkin.js Javascript fail, without throwing an error.

Web pages built with asp DO work.  Chrome, Firefox and IE9 on Windows work fine.  Safari on Macs work fine.  Disabling "Active Scripting" in IE8 restores functionality.

We phoned Marketo Support, who said an update that they pushed out yesterday (22 Feb 2012) apparently caused the problem.  Support became aware of the problem this morning and their engineering group is actively working on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to us also.  Every link on our site was disabled in IE7 and IE8.
We have had to remove all Marketo from our website and redeploy.
Marketo has admitted to the problem only after we worked like crazy to find it.
We couldn't even get notification because the support link was not working.
Ugly...

Jeff

Comment: We have found Marketo deployment to be poor quality, as well as their support team. One of their updates broke their emailing feature, a key reason we use their product, and they did not notify us. Customers who signed up did not receive a registration email and we weren't notified they were in the system. Who knows how many customers we lost... the support team told us we were being "too emotional" when we threatened dropping their product. Some companies just don't get it